# Uncaught ReferenceError: meteorInstall is not defined

Tags: reactjs, meteor

I am currently on a project using the tech stack meteor + react. I have a problem where I can't run the project because of undefined or not resolved modules. For more info look at the picture below. 
[Error got on the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYgRR.png)

The server of meteor runs perfectly, but when I access the site on my browser, it got that error. Anyone got into this problem, I need your help. :)

Comment: Nevermind guys, I fixed the problem. I installed the missing module, mongo-object, using meteor npm install mongo-object. :)

Answer (score 2):

You have not installed your required node modules. Either run meteor npm install mongo-object, or try npm install to install all missing npm dependencies.